# Is there a way to either get all Item's Access tokens, or delete all items associated with your Plaid ID?

Tags: plaid

Let's say you were mucking around in a developer instance of Plaid, with 25 accounts in use. As happens in development, the database exploded. So I do not have those access tokens anymore, but have 25 of the 100 slots used in my dev allotment.

I see how I might delete items -- if I had the access tokens. But is there any way to without the access tokens? Or a way of getting all access tokens associated with your plaid API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do it on your own, but even if there were, deleting access tokens doesn't free up slots in your dev environment. You can contact Support for help getting the tokens invalidated and/or getting your Dev token allocation increased.